# AngularJS: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I had this directive:

```
app.directive('customDropdown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/templates/directive_templates/customdropdown.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.custom-class);
        }
    }
})
```

Markup:

```
<custom-dropdown custom-class="custom-select-menu">

</custom-dropdown>
```

But, due to `console.log(attrs.custom-class)` I get the error mentioned in the question. It goes away when I change `custom-class` to just `custom`. Any idea why the error was popping up? Can't use hyphens?

Comment: javascript variable can't have hyphens thats why you have customDropdown, same for customClass too.

Comment: but they can in strict mode? right?

Comment: nope, you are typing `class`, thats why you get that error. you are substracting `class` from `attrs.custom`

Comment: No, variable names in strict mode follow the same rules as variables in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

`attrs.custom-class` custom-class is not a valid identifier in javascript. So you have 2 choices :

- Rename custom-class into something else without an hypen.
- Use the bracket syntax : `attrs['custom-class']`

Answer (score 0):

This means that you must declare strict mode by writing "use strict" at the beginning of the file or the function to use block-scope declarations.

```
function test(){
    "use strict";
    let a = 1;
}
```